# What is the difference between fill and foreground with shapes in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is there any difference between **fill** and **foreground** when used with **shapes**?

Both gave me same result in below code, is there any scenario where both may behave differently?

```
VStack(spacing: 30) {
     Text("He")
         .background(
              Circle()
                 .foregroundColor(.red)
          )
            
     Text("He")
         .background(
              Circle()
                .fill(.red)
          )
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a `.gradient` modifier with `.fill`: `.fill(.red.gradient)`, but you can't use  `.foregroundColor(.red.gradient)`. Also, of course `.fill` does not work with any kind of view - for example, you can't "fill" a `Text`.